# How to call a Twisted reactor from a file different from his?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet, twisted.client

I have a question that could well belong to Twisted or could be directly related to Python.

My problem, as the other is related to the disconnection process in Twisted.
As I read on this [site](https://jml.io/pages/how-to-disconnect-in-twisted-really.html), if I want to I have to perform the following steps:

1. The server must stop listening.
2. The client connection must disconnect.
3. The server connection must disconnect.

According to what I read on the previous page to make the first step would have to run the `stopListening` method.

In the example mentioned in the web all actions are performed in the same script. Making it easy to access the different variables and methods.

For me I have a server and a client are in different files and different locations.

I have a function that creates a server, and assigns a protocol and want, from the client protocol in another file, make an AMP call to a method for stop the connector.

The call AMP calls the SendMsg command.

```
class TESTServer(protocol.Protocol):

    factory = None
    sUsername = ""
    credProto = None
    bGSuser = None
    slot = None
"""
Here was uninteresting code.
"""
            #   upwards=self.bGSuser, forwarded=True, tx_timestamp=iTimestamp,\
            #    message=sMsg)

        log.msg("self.connector")
        log.msg(self.connector)

        return {'bResult': True}
    SendMsg.responder(vSendMsg)

    def _testfunction(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger('server')

        log.startLogging(sys.stdout)

        pf = CredAMPServerFactory()

        sslContext = ssl.DefaultOpenSSLContextFactory('key/server.pem',\
     'key/public.pem',)

        self.connector = reactor.listenSSL(1234, pf, contextFactory = sslContext,)

        log.msg('Server running...')
        reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TESTServer()._testfunction()
```

The class CredAMPServerFactory assign the corresponding protocol.

```
class CredAMPServerFactory(ServerFactory):

    """
    Server factory useful for creating L{CredReceiver} and L{SATNETServer} instances.

    This factory takes care of associating a L{Portal} with the L{CredReceiver}
    instances it creates. If the login is succesfully achieved, a L{SATNETServer}
    instance is also created.
    """
    protocol = CredReceiver
```

In the "CredReceiver" class I have a call that assigns the protocol to the TestServer class. I do this to make calls using the AMP method "Responder".

```
        self.protocol = SATNETServer
```

My problem is that when I make the call the program responds with an error indicating that the connector doesn't belong to CredReceiver attribute object.

```
  File "/home/sgongar/Dev/protocol/server_amp.py", line 248, in vSendMsg
    log.msg(self.connector)
exceptions.AttributeError: 'CredReceiver' object has no attribute 'connector'
```

How could I do this? Does anyone know of a similar example of that may take note?

Thank you.

***EDIT.***

*Server side:*

server_amp.py

1. Starts a reactor: `reactor.listenSSL(1234, pf, contextFactory =
   sslContext,)` from within the SATNETServer class.
2. Assigns protocol, `pf`, to `CredAMPServerFactory` class who belongs to module server.py also from within the SATNETServer class.

server.py

1. Within the class `CredAMPServerFactory` assigns `CredReceiver` class to protocol.
2. Once the connection is established the class `SATNETServer` is assigned to the protocol.

*Client side:*

client_amp

1. Makes a call to the `SendMsg` method belonging to the`SATNETServer` class.

Comment: I see no explicit connection between the title of the question, code  snippets, and your actual issue (`AttributeError`). Try to [create a minimal but complete code example that demonstrates the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The only way I know, at this time, to call a method of the server from the client is using an AMP call, although I put the connector in the protocol where I have the AMP calls, it doesn't recognize the object as existing in the server protocol. That is my question. I will try to create a shorter and concise code to help understanding the problem.